When using touchscreen, mouse cursor disappears - But doesn't come back when using the mouse again
On a computer with a touch screen (no trackpad) using Ubuntu 22.04.4
When touching the screen, the desired behavior is indeed to hide the mouse cursor.
However, if the user chooses to use the mouse again (moves it), it should un-hide the mouse cursor. That part doesn't happen.
Is there a fix or a workaround?

Can you check if that is fixed in 24.04? (Don't upgrade (it may cause issues) - download an ISO file of 24.04 and try it from live USB)
